# LINQ to Datatable - How to add an if condition in linq query where clause?

Tags: c#, linq, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

```
OleDbCommand commandSec = new OleDbCommand();
commandSec.CommandText = "SELECT [SectionName], [Strand], [ReqGrade], [GradeLevel] FROM tbl_section";
OleDbDataAdapter daSec = new OleDbDataAdapter(commandSec);
commandSec.Connection = conn;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
daSec.Fill(dt);
daSec.Fill(ds, "tbl_section");
var section = (from DataRow dr in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where (double)dr["ReqGrade"] >=  Convert.ToDouble(txt_genave.Text) &&
    (string)dr["GradeLevel"] == gradelevel
    select (string)dr["SectionName"]).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get an `InvalidCastException: Specified cast it not valid.`

I need to insert a class section to a particular student base on his/her GradeLevel and the ReqGrade.

Comment: Your question was to get an if condition but your error is invalid cast?

Comment: I want to change the reqgrade in where to an if condition because i get invalid cast sir.

Comment: The invalid cast has nothing to do with if-conditions. You are casting objects to `double` or `string`. These casts fails because the types are different(f.e. if `ReqGrade` is a `string` and not a `double`). But it's impossible to help further because we don't know the types in the database.

Comment: It is MS Access sir. The data type of ReqGrade is Number.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be here:

```
from DataRow dr in dt.AsEnumerable()
```

Try:

```
from DataRow dr in dt.Rows.AsEnumerable()
```

The `DataTable` itself is not enumerable, but the rows within it are.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue and avoid the error by changing

```cs
where (double)dr["ReqGrade"] >= ...
```

to

```cs
where Convert.ToDouble(dr["ReqGrade"]) >= ...
```